# How to make Scrapy spider to deny country domains

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to make my scrapy spider deny .com domains. What is the correct string to pass to deny_domains? I have tried "*.com" but it does not work.

Question UPDATE: How can i do the other way around? For example if i only want to scrape .com domains

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from myproject.items import MyprojectItem

class pformSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "pform6"

    start_urls = [
        "http://example.se",
    ]

    extractor = SgmlLinkExtractor(deny_domains=("*.com"))

    rules = (
        Rule(extractor,callback='parse_links',follow=True),
        )

    def parse_links(self, response):
        item = MyprojectItem()
        item['url'] = response.url
        yield item
```

Comment: Do you know what `*.` does in a regex?

Answer (score 3):

You can use scrapy.linkextractors

From http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html

> deny_domains (str or list) – a single value or a list of strings
>   containing domains which won’t be considered for extracting the links

But

> deny (a regular expression (or list of)) – a single regular expression
>   (or list of regular expressions) that the (absolute) urls must match
>   in order to be excluded (ie. not extracted).

So you can use a regex with "deny" I guess something like

```
".*\.com\/.*"
```

But it may match elsewhere in the URL.

Comment: Ok, is it possible to do the other way around, if i want to only scrape .com domains?

Comment: You could use the same regex with allow - "allow (a regular expression (or list of)) – a single regular expression (or list of regular expressions) that the (absolute) urls must match in order to be extracted."

Answer (score 3):

```
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
...
    rules=(
        Rule(LinkExtractor(deny=('.+\.com', ))),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.9/topics/link-extractors.html) I'd say you need to do something like this:

```
extractor = SgmlLinkExtractor(allow="*.com")
```

Note: I didn't test this.

> Parameters:    allow (str or list) – a single regular expression (or
>   list of regular expressions) that the (absolute) urls must match in
>   order to be extracted. If not given (or empty), it will match all
>   links.